# Cannot access firewalled jboss server from Internet Explorer

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, internet-explorer, jboss

I've produced a website for a client [One Single Menu](http://onesinglemenu.com/) using JBoss and hosted it on Rackspace Cloud Servers running Ubuntu's Maverick Meerkat. Following advice, I esablished some iptables rule to protect jboss:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

Now, several versions of IE on several computers on at least two different ISPs cannot access the onesinglemenu.com. Curl from within the datacenter, Firefox, and Safari on the same ISPs can all access the server fine. I even tried IE and Firefox on the same computer and IE failed but Firefox worked.

The error behaviour is that IE hangs on connecting without reporting an error, even after a minute or so. No page is displayed at all.

I find it quite odd that I'm having a browser specific connection issue, but it appears to be the case. Help!

Comment: Ahah, the tumbleweed badge! FYI this appears to be a very very bad HTML parsing issue. Wireshark shows the HTML being transfered but it looks exactly like a connection issue in the browser. It remains unsolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the content-type header is set to "text/xml;charset=UTF-8" above a XHTML document then apparently IE will fail and die, as if there had been problem connecting to the server (with the exception that there is no obvious time-out).

Hopefully this question will make the issue easier to find in search engines under connection related keywords.